# Opera Mobile not allowing jQuery clicks

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, opera-mini

I have been testing out the foundation CSS framework and am quite liking their custom form elements that the framework provides.

I have built a page, `http://eventgrapple.com/home`, to test the framework out, and it works fine in [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) and so on (desktop) (slightly buggy in [Internet Explorer 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7)) and works fine with a BlackBerry's native browser, but none of the form elements work in [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 6.5 for [BlackBerry bold 9700](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Bold#BlackBerry_Bold_9700).

The link to the framework is `http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/forms.php`. How can I fix this or is there an alternative?

Comment: You should post the code here, the app you've linked to is throwing SQL exceptions. Specify what is not working for you, on what version of Opera (desktop or Mobile or mini). Opera has its own issues and many poorly written AJAX applications are working on everything except Opera...

Comment: i have updated my code since posting the question- I'm on opera mini 6.5.27548 and the custom forms do not work- even the ones listed in the foundation framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera Mini has very limited JavaScript support. JavaScript is executed on Opera's servers when you submit something or click a link, so don't expect JavaScript frameworks to work correctly on it. Read more at: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-web-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript

Find some dedicated framework, or write from scratch following the guidelines from the article.

Comment: pretty pointless of using a framework for mobile development then

Comment: Opera Mini is designed for non-smart phones, so it's functionality is very limited.