# jquery on() selector not working on mobile browsers/dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having problem with jquery on selector.
When I am using

```
$('.class').on("click",function(){
//Code
});
```

its working on mobile devices but fails to select dynamically created content
so I changed to

```
$( document ).on('click', '.class' ,function(){
//Code
});
```

Now that it works for dynamically created contents but is no longer supported on mobile browsers such as *Opera Mini* or *Uc Browser* How can I make it work on all conditions.

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Worth reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650408/opera-mobile-not-allowing-jquery-clicks

Comment: Already read before posting And as I said using 1st method works on opera mini

Comment: Okay... but have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090942/jquery-on-method-not-working-on-dynamic-content

Comment: Yaa read it too and that is my 2nd method which is not working on opera mini

Comment: If you add the two readings together... what do you get?

Comment: In all seriousness, you may be fighting a losing battle: http://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript

Comment: @wildandjam- It wasn't so helpful for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally Resolved it of My own:

add the required code in an function:
and take an variable temp to store temporary boolean value

```
var temp=true;
function function($this){
//Code
}

$('.class').on("click",function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    function($this);
    temp=false;//making temp false to avoid re execution.
});

$( document ).on('click', '.class' ,function(){
    if(temp){
        var $this = $(this);
        function($this);
    }else{
        temp=true;//making temp true for next event.
    }
});
```

Comment: You could have easily used $.one or $.off instead of this complex code.

Comment: @DhruvPathak- Sir Will You Kindly Add an answer using the method you mentioned ?