# MySQL values not updating when using Opera mini and UC browser?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have this code to call run myupdate.php everytime a link with .two class is clicked.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="customstyle.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".two").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "myupdate.php",
                data : {action_type:"update"},
                success : function(html){
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is my code for myupdate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['login']){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
}

function updatepoints() {
    mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Cannot connect to database");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT *from member WHERE username='" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $points = $row["points"];
    $points = $points + 2;
    mysql_query("UPDATE member set points='" . $points . "' WHERE username='" .   $_SESSION["username"] . "'");
}
if($_POST['action_type'] == 'update') {
    updatepoints();
}
?>
```

What one have to do is visit the page click on any link containing class .two and when he refreshes the page his points increase by two.
This code works on all browsers on PC, Firefox for android and other such browsers, it works in built in browser in android. However, it does not work in opera mini and UC browser. Do UC browser and opera mini have some problem with executing php code written in this way or they don't register these events as clicks.

Comment: PHP code runs on the server side and the browser has nothing to do with it. If MySQL+PHP code is working fine in all browsers but Opera Mini/UC browser, chances are that the error is with the JavaScript (maybe for some reason they don't make the AJAX call or there's an error and they stop processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another user mentions [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650408/opera-mobile-not-allowing-jquery-clicks), Opera Mini has very limited JavaScript support. In the link https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/#javascript you can read why your click event may not work on Opera Mini:

> Mini supports JavaScript as well as Opera Desktop, but instead of
>   running on the client, it runs on the server. [...]
>
> The server doesn't render to the phone constantly; instead, it takes a
>   snapshot of the page after it has been loaded, pauses all running
>   scripts, and sends that to the phone. This means that while Mini
>   supports JavaScript just as well as Opera Desktop, interactivity is
>   somewhat more limited. [...]
>
> For authors, the upshot of all this is that once a page has been
>   rendered by the server, it won't change until the user does something
>   on that and there is no way for scripts to run in the background. The
>   user must do something to make Mini talk to the server in order for
>   JavaScript to be unpaused. **As a result, you cannot expect things
>   like JavaScript animations or timed Ajax updates to work in the
>   background as they would on a desktop browser**.

So, as I mentioned in the comment, it's not that Opera Mini has problems with PHP (that runs on the server side), it has problems with the JavaScript and the AJAX call (on the client/browser side).

Comment: Is there any work around that I can use. Any link that might be helpful?

Comment: As a recommendation, you should clean the code: stop using `mysql` functions (deprecated) and move to `mysqli` or `PDO`, start using parameterized SQL statements, sanitize inputs before running them on the database (never trust a user input, not event he session data), select only the fields that you'll need in a SQL query (I don't know the size of the `member` table, but you only need `points` and select every single column with the *), you could merge those two SQL statements into only one `UPDATE`...

Comment: A quick search online shows that there's an article in Opera Dev with the title: Designing With Opera Mini in Mind (https://dev.opera.com/articles/designing-with-opera-mini-in-mind/) that different SO users recommended when having trouble with AJAX in Opera Mini. Sadly, the link is broken (returns a 404), but I know for experience that Opera stores all the old articles in a github repository. Let me look for the URL to the repository and I'll post it as a comment

Comment: Here you have it from their github repository: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera-static-backup/blob/master/http/dev.opera.com/articles/view/designing-with-opera-mini-in-mind/index.html but it doesn't give much information :S